# How to change Calendar military time to eastern standard?

Tags: calendar

Below is an image of a calendar entry. The time is in military time and there are also a pair of rogue parenthesis after the time display.

[image]

I want to know how to convert this to eastern standard time and remove the parenthesis. I went into the Plug ins Javascript file and I understand how to remove the time altogether but that's not what I want.

The WordPress instance already has it's General time set to eastern standard with a non military format.

Comment: This looks like a plugin. Which one?

Comment: It's using wpengine and its listed under 'widgets' but not plug ins.